# Why do I use separation of variables for finite domain,Laplace transform for semi-finite and Fourier transform for infinite domains in 2nd order PDES?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I can't seem to find a proof or derivation which provides a reason for using these methods in different domains and I hoped for one here.

Comment: A finite domain necessarily has an infinite set of _discrete_ modes, where as an infinite domain necessarily has a infinite _continuum_ of modes.